# How to access data on different Google Spreadsheet through Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing a Google Apps Script on my Google Site and am trying to use data that is provides on 2 different tabs in a Google Spreadsheet. From what I thought I understood from the documentation I could use all available methods in the `SpreadsheetApp` class on a Sites script by just using the `openById()` method.

Anyway here is what I tried to do

```
function doGet(e) {

    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID_GOES_HERE).getActiveSheet();
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(doc.getSheetId()[1]);

    //....
}
```

I get the error

> Cannot find method setActiveSheet(. (line 4)

I'm pulling my work off this link: [Storing Data in Google Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/storing_data_spreadsheets) and also the Ui Service section listed under Building User Interfaces.

Anybody seeing what I'm doing wrong in these two lines?

Comment: I'd suggest you should make use of the autocomplete feature of the script editor to avoid syntax error or using methods that don't apply... it's an easy way to start without annoying errors and/or typos ;-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

setActiveSheet should be used only with the spreadsheet displayed by the UI, a sheet in a spreadsheet you have opened in your browser.

With SpreadsheetApp.openById you are opening a spreadsheet to access its data, but it doesn't open in your browser.  It hasn't an UI.

I found this comments in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheetapp?hl=es-ES#openById :

```
// The code below opens a spreadsheet using it's ID and gets the name for it.
// Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
// It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");
```

Some examples assume your script is running into your spreadsheet.  It's not your case, because you are running a script as a service, which should have its own User Interface.

Comment: That is a little disappointing. Do you happen to know of a way to access data on different tabs then through a service not running inside the Spreadsheet?

Comment: simply use getSheetByName('the name of the sheet'), by default it is 'Sheet1' unless you renamed it or if your not using English... for example in French the default value is 'Feuille1'

Comment: getSheets() will bring you an array with all the sheets in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @YoArgentino  I do the following, works fine even when the spreadsheet is not displayed.         spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(liveSheet);
spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

Answer (score 7):

I think @megabyte1024 addresses the syntax errors, but in answer to your comment to @YoArgentina:

> Do you happen to know of a way to access data on different tabs then
>   through a service not running inside the Spreadsheet?

Does this sort of help?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID_GOES_HERE);
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
// the variable sheets is an array of Sheet objects
var sheet1A1 = sheets[0].getRange('A1').getValue();
var sheet2A1 = sheets[1].getRange('A1').getValue();
```

Comment: Looks like getSheets() isn't accessible in outside a Spreadsheet script => TypeError: Cannot find function getSheets in object Sheet. (line 4)

Comment: Are you sure you are _not_ using `var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID_GOES_HERE).getActiveSheet();` as in your original post? With the code in this post, `ss` should be a Spreadsheet object, not a Sheet object.

Comment: Yes you are 100% correct. I completely missed that. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

You need to access each sheet separately.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID_GOES_HERE);
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // "access data on different tabs"
ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
```

Comment: "Do you happen to know of a way to access data on different tabs then through a service not running inside the Spreadsheet?"

var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0];

Comment: It looks like I don't have access to that method through the standalone service. Seems like I have to use getSheetID(), getSheetName(), and getSheetValues()

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one problem in these two lines. The 1st one is that the [setActiveSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheetapp#setActiveSheet) method parameters is a Sheet class object and the getSheetId method returns an integer value. By the way this method (getSheetId) is [not documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet). The 2nd problem can happen if the SpreadsheetApp has no active spreadsheet. In this case there is the "Please select an active spreadsheet first." error. Use the [SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheetapp#setActiveSpreadsheet) method to set an active spreadsheet.