# Opening and visualizing a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Is there any method to open and visualize with **javascript** a **google spreadsheet**?

In other words I would like to create a *script* in the Google ***spreadsheet A***,which would be able to physically open and select the ***spreadsheet B***. By Looking at `Google Script API` - I saw that it is possible to use the `SpreadsheetApp.openbyID()` method;but it doesn't physically open the spreadsheet and select a specific sheet.

Can somebody tell me if this is possible and what **API command** should be used for the purpose?

Comment: Do you mean, open the spreadsheet in the browser? I have never seen that in the API. I suspect you need your java script to be loaded into the browser to make it work.

Comment: Note: "SpreadsheetApp.openbyID()" is google apps script and runs on a server, not in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by embed JavaScript to the google spreadshoot page.

For that, you can user userscripts or to developer your an extension for google chrome.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. Could you please be more specific on how to  do it. (I am a newbie of javascript and google api). do you have any link or reference on "embedding javascript to google spreadsheet" or "userscript"? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, from [How to access data on different Google Spreadsheet through Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727975/how-to-access-data-on-different-google-spreadsheet-through-google-apps-script):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID_GOES_HERE);
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
// the variable sheets is an array of Sheet objects
var sheet1A1 = sheets[0].getRange('A1').getValue();
var sheet2A1 = sheets[1].getRange('A1').getValue();
```

you can open by sheet name, but using the sheet number is faster because it does not require a network call.