# How to reference a specific sheet in the Google scripts editor?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I've tried a ton of different things here with no success. Basically, I need to receive an email notification when a value in either column A or E is changed/removed. The following code works, but doesn't differentiate between sheets. So every time column A or E is edited in another sheet, I get an email notification. Any help is much appreciated.

The Screenshot of my script

[image]

Comment: **don't** post code as screenshots! it is **text**, so edit your question and include your code **as text** - and take care of proper formatting. select your code and press ctrl-k to mark it as code.

Comment: You may want to try using [`openById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=es-ES#openById(String)) which basically opens the spreadsheet with the given ID and spreadsheet ID can be extracted from its URL. In addition to that, please also check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11729301) and see if it will help you.